# What "bastards" is Karen referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, goodfellas

Karen is upset after seeing Janice’s name on her husband’s prison visitation list.
Karen brought her kids to the prison to confront her husband, Michael:

> Karen: I saw her name on the register. Want her to visit you? Let her
> stay up all night crying and writing to the parole board. Let her
> sneak this stuff in for you every week. Let her fight these  **bastards**
> every week!

What "bastards" is Karen referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Likely, the prison guards

Certainly, it's unclear who she is referring to but given the context (she is smuggling contraband into the prison) and that she is angry she is exaggerating her interactions with the guards.

The treatment she gets when entering the prison is cursory at best (the search is minimal at best) so it is more that likely that she is indulging in hyperbole when calling them "creep bastards".

The only context seems to be "every week" which would line up with the weekly prison visits.